# Caracteres especiais (ï»¿) aparecem na frente da tag XML

Tags: php, xml

Estou lendo dois arquivos XML's porém criados em computadores diferentes. Este primeiro foi criado no meu computador:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> ...
```

Já este abaixo com mesmo conteúdo aparece uma sequência de caracteres especiais (`ï»¿`) antes de da *tag* `xml`. Veja:

```
ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> ...
```

Mesmo copiando o conteúdo de um arquivo e colando em outro, ainda assim na hora de usar o `new SimpleXMLElement($contentFile)` continua da mesma forma.

Como esses caracteres estranhos aparecem, acaba ocorrendo um erro:

> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error
>   : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found in C:\wamp64\www...

A princípio pensei remover estes caracteres usando expressão regular, mas pensei que talvez já existe algo pronto em relação a isso (que ainda desconheço);

Como posso corrigir este problema?

Comment: cade os dois arquivo xml?

Comment: Relacionada no SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3255993/1452488

Comment: @VirgilioNovic o problema só está no início do arquivo, por isso achei irrelevante inserir todo. Então estou usando reticencias...

Comment: Esses dois arquivos são criados por quem?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Vc acha mesmo relevante isso para dar uma resposta?! Um por mim e outro por minha prima. Bloco de notas no meu pc e bloco de notas no pc dela. xD

Comment: Claro que eu acho relevante @acklay pode ser que os editores estão em codificações diferentes, temos que levar em conta todo o processo, essa é minha visão ( não vejo nada inclusive ) para tentar ajudar.

Comment: Viu a resposta @acklay como é de grande utilidade dizer como os arquivos foram criados.!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Mas é porque é o seguinte, "minha prima" criou um arquivo através de um software de geolocalização bla bla bla... Ai tentou subir para o sistema, no qual estava dando erro. Pedi pra ela me enviar, dai então não funcionou. Quando fui debugar, apareceu esses caracteres especiais na frente, no qual os arquivos gerados no meu pc não faz isso.

Comment: @acklay sim claro...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Os caracteres `ï»¿` indicam que o documento foi salvo com *"UTF-8 com BOM"*, quando deveria salvar *"sem BOM"*.

### Como tentar resolver na aplicação

> **Nota:** nos exemplos usei [`simplexml_load_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php), mas tanto ele quanto o `simplexml_load_file` retorna um `SimpleXMLElement`:
>
> [**`SimpleXMLElement`**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) *`simplexml_load_string ( string $data [, string $class_name = "SimpleXMLElement" [, int $options = 0 [, string $ns = "" [, bool $is_prefix = false ]]]] )`*

Não tenho como afirmar qual documento é, você pode tentar decodificar o conteúdo do XML antes do "parse":

```php
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$data = utf8_decode($data);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

...

$xml->asXML();
```

Ou decodificar e codificar novamente (acaso tenha algum problema pelo XML estar com UTF-8 no cabeçalho):

```php
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$data = utf8_decode($data);
$data = utf8_encode($data);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

...

$xml->asXML();
```

Você pode optar por tentar usar o **[`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)** (este por sinal foi o único que funcionou para mim):

```php
$data = file_get_contents('A.xml');

$data = trim($data); //Remove os espaçamentos incluindo o "BOM"

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

...

$xml->asXML();
```

Se nenhum funcionar pode tentar o `substr` com `strpos` assim:

```php
$data = file_get_contents($url);

$data = substr($data, strpos($data, '<'));

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

...

$xml->asXML();
```

Ainda se falhar, pode combinar com `utf8_decode` e `utf8_encode` novamente:

```php
$data = file_get_contents($url);

$data = substr($data, strpos($data, '<'));

$data = utf8_decode($data);
$data = utf8_encode($data);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

...

$xml->asXML();
```

### Como resolver com editores/processadores de texto

Se tiver acesso a estes `.xml` você pode edita-los usando o notepad++:

[image: notepad++]

Ou sublimetext:

[image: sublimetext]

Comment: Me desculpe, mas não vou ter acesso ao XML. Na verdade os gerenciadores dos sistema criarão o XML baseado em um software de geolocalização. Não quero nem saber como eles estão gerando esses arquivos, só tem que estar em um formato que o sistema pode interpretar(no caso é o que quero fazer). Também não vou dar instruções pra ninguém instalar/abrir tanto o noteped++/sublime. O sistema deve ler e verificar se está com BOM ou sem BOM e fazer o tratamento adequado(que é o que quero fazer). Talvez eu não tenha soube demostrar totalmente o problema em si, mas de fato, sua resposta não vai me ajudar.

Comment: Agradeço imensamente pela resposta Bro e por tentar ajudar. =D Vou pesquisar mais um pouco, e talvez, tentar adaptar a pergunta para que sua resposta seja validada. Caso eu não encontre uma solução, vou tentar criar uma nova pergunta com de fato o problema. =D

Comment: @acklay mas a dica do `trim` não resolveu o problema do BOM? Porque no teste que fiz funcionou, eu li um XML remoto com `file_get_contents` usei `trim` e depois apliquei a string no `simplexml_load_string` e reconheceu.

Comment: @acklay editei a resposta com outra sugestão do `substr` e `strpos`

Comment: O trim não funcionou comigo. Então, você viu que eu citei o `SimpleXMLElement`. Já trabalhou com ele!? Pois bem, essa "classe" em vez de receber uma URL do arquivo como está na pergunta (que acabei editando), ela recebe o conteúdo do arquivo, ai eu uso o `$xml->asXML()` para reconhecer esse conteúdo sendo como `xml`. Só que ao receber o conteúdo via POST, quando chamo o `SimpleXMLElement($contentFile)`, já dá erro com os caracteres especiais. Tentei usar o trim no $contentFile, mas não funfou.

Comment: @acklay o `simplexml_load_string` é um atalho para o `SimpleXMLElement`. Por isso em todos exemplos eu usei ele, veja na doc o tipo do `return`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

Comment: BOM hahaha, já deu né?! Usei o utf8_decode e funcionou beleza! Desculpe a petulância, e obrigado pela paciência! (+1) admirador(no bom sentido - huehe) aqui do SO. Abs.