# Retirar espaços em brancos da lista em Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estou lendo um arquivo, *stopwords.txt*, e neste arquivo cada *stopword* está em uma linha, exemplo:

```
a


o


para
```

Cada *stopword* estou salvando em uma lista da seguinte maneira:

```
with open(sys.argv[1],"r") as file_entrada: 
    lista_nome_base_docs = [line.rstrip() for line in file_entrada]


with open(sys.argv[2],"r") as file_stopwords:  
    lista_stopwords = [line.strip() for line in file_stopwords]
```

Após essa leitura, mando exibir a lista na tela e sai desse jeito

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entre as *stopwords*, está saindo um espaço em branco, exemplo: `['a','','para']`

Como faço para não aparecer esses espaços em branco na lista?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta fazer a verificação quando você gera a lista de palavras:

```
lista_stopwords = [line.strip() for line in file_stopwords if line.strip() != ""]
```

Perceba a adição da condição `if line.strip() != ""` ao final da linha. Com isso você já garantirá que apenas as linhas com algum conteúdo diferente de da quebra de linha não sejam incluídas na lista.

Veja um exemplo:

```
words = ["a\n", "\n", "ok\n", "\n", ""]

print([word.strip() for word in words if word.strip() != ""])

# ['a', 'ok']
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/TnT3nZ) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/MJBt/0)</sup>

Comment: Entendi @Anderson Calos Woss, uma outra coisa que não entendi o por que, na imagem da pergunta que mostra a saída da lista, repare que a primeira posição da lista, está imprimindo um "lixo" pelo que me parece, sabe me dizer o que seria isso? ou como remover isto, para que na primeira posição da lista imprima a primeira stopword de fato.

Comment: @WilliamHenrique é os caracteres do BOM (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9940/5878). Esta resposta pode te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/217650/5878.

Comment: consegui aqui tirar ele... usando o que você mostrou, naquele if adicionei mais uma condição: if line.strip() != "" and line.strip() != "ï»¿" - e eliminou esses caracteres especiais da lista, ficou somentes as stopwords. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!